# Gradle Logging Output Levels

Tags: java, logging, gradle

In my project classes I've used `java.util.logging.Logger` and added various log output's throughout my code, using various log  levels ie.

**src/main/java/Run.java**

```
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class Run{


    public static void main( String args[] ){
      System.out.println("Hello World");

      logger.log(Level.CONFIG, "Just some config info");
      Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Run.class.getName());
      logger.log(Level.INFO, "Just logging some info");
      logger.log(Level.FINE, "Fine logging");
      logger.log(Level.FINER, "Finer logging");
      logger.log(Level.WARNING, "This is a warning log!");

    }
}
```

Currently when I run `gradle -i test` all log messages with the `Level.INFO` defined are shown but none of the config, warn or fine messages are output.

I've tried updating my **build.gradle** file such that:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin:'application'
mainClassName = "Run"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testCompile "junit:junit:4.11"
}

run{
    systemProperties = ['java.util.logging.config.file' : 'logging.properties']
}
```

I've included:

```
systemProperties = ['java.util.logging.config.file' : 'logging.properties']
```

Then created **/src/main/resource/logging.propertiess**

```
handlers= java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler
.level= CONFIG
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level = FINER
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter = java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter
```

Running:

```
gradle run
```

I get:

```
:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:classes UP-TO-DATE
:run
Hello World

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
```

And when running *gradle -i run* I get:
    Successfully started process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_20.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java''
    Hello World
    :run (Thread[main,5,main]) completed. Took 0.202 secs.

```
BUILD SUCCESSFUL
```

ie. no logging information. However commenting out the system.properties from within the run task and re-running *gradle -i run* I get:

```
Successfully started process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_20.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java''
Hello World
Nov 05, 2014 12:07:42 PM Run main
INFO: Just logging some info
Nov 05, 2014 12:07:42 PM Run main
WARNING: This is a warning log!
:run (Thread[main,5,main]) completed. Took 0.229 secs.

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
```

The info and warning level logs, but not the fine or finer ones.

tldr;

How do I get the config, fine & finer level logs to log to the console in a generic gradle java project ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Several options (**I personally prefer option 2.2**):

**1) Custom logging.properties file:**

The Java Logging API has a default logging configuration file at `<JRE_HOME>/lib/logging.properties`. You can use your own config file setting the JVM property `java.util.logging.config.file`.

```
handlers = java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler

Run.handlers = java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler
Run.level = FINER
Run.useParentHandlers = false

java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level = ALL
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter = java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter
```

You have to set `useParentHandlers = false` to avoid getting duplicate prints from parent handlers.

*1.1) Set above property with absolute path*

Did not even try ;-)

*1.2) Load custom file as follows in `Run.java`*

Loading it as follows in `Run.java`:

```
    InputStream inputStream = Run.class.getResourceAsStream("mylogging.properties");
    try {
        LogManager.getLogManager().readConfiguration(inputStream);
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

**2) Custom system property (i.e.: `logLevel`)**

Define a `systemProperty` in your **`build.gradle`**:

```
run {
    systemProperty 'logLevel', System.getProperty('logLevel')
}
```

Add a `defaultLogLevel` in `Run.java`:

```
public static Level defaultLevel = Level.INFO;
```

Get the value of `logLevel` property:

```
String logLevel = System.getProperty("logLevel");
```

And set the defined level in logger:

```
Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Run.class.getName());
logger.setLevel(logLevel.isEmpty() ? defaultLevel : Level.parse(logLevel));
```

*2.1) Create a new `ConsoleHandler` and switch-off  print from parent handlers*

```
    System.out.println(Run.class.getName());
    Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Run.class.getName());
    logger.setLevel(logLevel.isEmpty() ? defaultLevel : Level.parse(logLevel));

    Handler consoleHandler = new ConsoleHandler();
    consoleHandler.setLevel(logLevel.isEmpty() ? defaultLevel : Level.parse(logLevel));
    logger.addHandler(consoleHandler);

    logger.setUseParentHandlers(false);
```

*2.2) Find parent `ConsoleHandler` and set defined level*

```
    Logger topLogger = Logger.getLogger("");

    Handler consoleHandler = null;
    for (Handler handler : topLogger.getHandlers()) {
        if (handler instanceof ConsoleHandler) {
            //found the console handler
            consoleHandler = handler;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (consoleHandler == null) {
        // not found, create a new one
        consoleHandler = new ConsoleHandler();
        topLogger.addHandler(consoleHandler);
    }
    //set the console handler level
    consoleHandler.setLevel(logLevel.isEmpty() ? defaultLevel : Level.parse(logLevel));
```

With that, `gradle run` yields messages above the default level (INFO). With

```
gradle run -DlogLevel=FINE
```

you can control which messages are shown.

Comment: If using SLF4J with logback, be aware that interface `org.slf4j.Logger` does not have the method `setLevel`.  But `ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger` implements this interface and has this method.  To create the `Logger` you therefore have to import the latter class instead, and then cast as follows: `Logger LOGGER = (Logger)LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyClass.class)`